# Set default css of input type button

Tags: html, css

I am applying a background image on input type button. for this i have written my code in style.css. But now i want that button will look like as it is default, but my restriction is that i can not delete css style from style.css. But i can override it in other css style1.css.
so how can i override this?

style.css

```
button
{
background:red;
}
```

if i override like this it shows nothing.

style1.css

```
button
{
background:none;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381100/reverting-css-style-of-input-type-submit-button-to-its-default-style

Answer (score 3):

Probably a duplicate question for [**Can you style html form buttons with css?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950238/can-you-style-html-form-buttons-with-css).

Well, as far as button or any other input type is considered you can do that by adding this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Application" id="submit" />
```

**CSS**

```
#submit {
    background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:6px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: poiner;
     border:none;
}



#submit:hover {
    border: none;
    background:red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;

}
```

You can even try this,

```
input[type="submit"]{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

or even, you can add a class:

```
.my_button_type
 {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

You can apply inline styling also:

```
<input type="button" style="background: #333; border: 0px;" />
```

So, you have many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use inline styles, or use `!important`.

Example:

style1.css

```
    button
    {
         background:none !important;
    }
```

Or inline:

```
<button style="background: none;">
```

Comment: Please do not use `!important` in CSS, it's very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
button { background:none !important; }
```

Comment: I have to set default look of button(Looks like Windows-made), doing like yours will not work:(

Answer (score 0):

First, precedence is important:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
```

You must put the css file after the original css that you want to overwrite.

Second, in your `style1.css`, there are so many approach do achieve what you want. Like cancelling out the css style that you want to overwrite

```
//style.css
button {
    background: url("...");
}

//style1.css
button {
    background: none;
}
```

or using `!important` to attributes you want to implement.